# Django 1.5: Display foreignkey values in both admin models

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I'm not sure that my title really made sense. Basically (from the code below), when I access the admin screen, I want a project to display with its client and a client to display all attached projects. Is there any way to do this?

```
class Client(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    #project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    #status = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Project(models.Model):
    project_choices = (
        ('L1', 'Lead'),
        ('C1', 'Confirmed'),
        ('P1', 'In Progress'),
        ('P1', 'Paid'),

    )
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Project Title', max_length=250, null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    project_status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=project_choices,
                                      default='P1')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest setting up a custom [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) and using the list_display to indicate which fields you want to show in the admin.  It is fairly customizable, and you can add callables that could display exactly the info you indicate.  An example ModelAdmin for the Client Model is below.

```
# project/app/admin.py
# Callable to add to ModelAdmin List Display
def show_client_projects(obj):
    project_list = [p.title for p in obj.project_set.all()]
    return ', '.join(project_list)
show_client_projects.short_description = 'Client Projects'

# Custom ModelAdmin
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'show_client_projects')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create ModelAdmin classes for your models to define columns to display in the built-in Django admin:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

This is particularly relevant:

```
ManyToManyField fields aren’t supported, because that would entail executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add that method’s name to list_display. (See below for more on custom methods in list_display.)
```

So, you can create a method for your Client which loads up the Client's projects, and include that in the `list_display`.

Something like this should put you on the right track:

```
# In your models.py...
from django.contrib import admin

class Client(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    def projects(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(client=self)


class ClientAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','projects',)
admin.site.register(Client,ClientAdmin)
```